# Using interfaces to setup the classes behaviour

Tags: java

I'm not sure whether or not this is good practice:

I have an interface for my commands (I do spigot development) so I can handle my commands a lot easier,

here's the snippet of my interface

```java
public interface exampleInterface{

boolean onCommand(CommandSender arg0, Command arg1, String arg2, String[] arg3);

    PlayerGroup commandRank();

    boolean allowPlayerSender();
    boolean allowConsoleSender();


}
```

And when I implement it to my command classes, I'll override and either return true or false for those booleans etc.

Is this generally an okay practice or should I be doing something else?

Comment: *Generally* speaking this can be a good idea, but we'd need more detail to say whether your selection of methods is sound.

Comment: Do you mean how i process the command interface in my handler?

Comment: From the point of view of the software architecture your question is really a good question. Which kind of answer are you looking for? I mean, do you want to know what are the software engineering best practices?

Comment: Yeah, what would be the best way to go about this? If i were to get an interview by a few Java developers how would they expect me to handle the design of my "sub command" handlers, which is basically me splitting up a base commands arguments and processing them through another class. example: /mycommand (That'd be my base) and /mycommand <arg0> (that gets processed by my handler, then if everythings good, gets executed by the class that i assigned it to) which makes long command classes really simple to work with, as i dont have a class with 700 lines of code (for example) it gets split up